# Ellipsis to appear at a particular position

Tags: android, xml

I have a problem with layout in my program, actually am using 3 text views aligned right to right such that three text views looks like in a line . i have given android single line = true for all three. MY problem is i want the ellipsis to appear at a particular position , that is after a particular size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm interpreting "size" correctly as at a certain width: Add paddingRight or marginRight to the last TextView. That will shift the whole text area to the left and thus the ellipsis, too.

If you want the ellipsis to be after a specific line, e.g. line 3, add these to your TextViews:

```
android:maxLines="3"
android:minLines="3"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Comment: Not working...actually it not a single text view ,combinations of textviews, that should end within a particular limit

Comment: You have to explain "within a particular limit". Maybe show in a picture what you have and what you want?

Comment: for example,
hi How are you,had your lunch,good morning....   these three are my three text views separated by coma, i have given single line true , so ellipsis is occurring after morning , what to do to make ellipsis occurring say after good ??

Comment: So you mean after a certain word? I don't think Android offers this natively. You could realize this in a custom view, but that probably isn't worth the trouble.

Comment: not certain to be after a word, if after a position or a cutoff in view

Comment: Then I still think paddingRight="the position you want in dp" together with ellipsize="end" should work, but only set it for the last TextView.

Comment: Nice :) Please accept my answer then (click the tick left of it).